# Parallelize Hibernate Initializations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm having a problem trying to initialize a list of objects in Hibernate (Hibernate.initialize()) in parallel, it takes too long to initialize one object, so I thought I can take advantage of parallelism in my case.

I tried using parallelStream() but the execution time didn't change and it seems that I'm not having a parallel execution.

```
public Collection<MyType> getResults(multipleObjectsToBeInitialized) {
List<MyType> result = multipleObjectsToBeInitialized
                    .parallelStream()
                    .filter(myObject -> acceptObject(myObject))
                    .map(myObject -> {
                        Hibernate.initialize(myObject);
                        return myObject;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Note that this method is called by another with @Transactional annotation to manage transactions.

Comment: How many objects roughly in `multipleObjectsToBeInitialized`? Might end up in a costly *select n+1*, which should be addressed in another way (e.g. by *join-fetching* the initial query).

Comment: There are 15 objects, I know it is not a lot but if I manage to parallelize the execution   on the 4 cores in my machine, gains should be pretty visible